# Mahalanobis distance in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, statistics, pca

I am trying to find the Mahalanobis distance of some points from the origin.The MATLAB command for that is mahal(Y,X)

But if I use this I get NaN as the matrix X =0 as the distance needs to be found from the origin.Can someone please help me with this.How should it be done

Comment: Please show inputs to the `mahal` command.

Comment: Inputs to the mahal command are a Y matrix of 407000*3 and X matrix which should be the origin and since MATLAB needs X to have more rows than columns its a 4*3 matrix of zeros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are a bit confused about what `mahal()` is doing. First, computation of the Mahalanobis distance requires a population of points, from which the covariance will be calculated.

In the [Matlab docs for this function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/mahal.html) it makes it clear that the distance being computed is:

```
d(I) = (Y(I,:)-mu)*inv(SIGMA)*(Y(I,:)-mu)'
```

where `mu` is the population average of `X` and `SIGMA` is the population covariance matrix of `X`. Since your population consists of a single point (the origin), it has no covariance, and so the `SIGMA` matrix is not invertible, hence the error where you get NaN/Inf values in the distances.

If you know the covariance structure that you want to use for the Mahalanobis distance, then you can just use the formula above to compute it for yourself. Let's say that the covariance you care about is stored in a matrix `S`. You want the distance w.r.t. the origin, so you don't need to subtract anything from the values in `Y`, all you need to compute is:

```
for ii = 1:size(Y,1)
    d(ii) = Y(ii,:)*inv(S)*Y(ii,:)'; % Where Y(ii,:) is assumed to be a row vector.'
end
```

Comment: Yes that is the problem.It says in the documentation that Y is the set of points from which you want to calculate the distance and mu and sigma are sample mean and covariance.Since I am doing PCA the mean is zero as I am working in the PCA space.I want distance of each point from the new origin.Then how should i do it

Comment: You need to calculate the covariance of your new points in the PCA space. Mahalanobis distance requires a covariance, first and foremost.  There must be some set of points, and then you transformed them by projection with PCA, and now those projected points have a new mean, and a covariance. If you put all those points into the `X` matrix, then your original code will work to compute distance from the new mean. Otherwise, if the new mean is supposed to theoretically be zero, just compute the covariance of the projected points yourself and use the formula for the distance calculation.

Comment: Well I tried using the formula above.my Y is a 40700*3 matrix where each row has 3 columns since its a RGB image and every row corresponds to one pixel.The covariance matrix is a 3*3 matrix.So the above formula gives me a 3*3 matrix.But should I not get a 40700*1  matrix if I want to find the distance from every point.Thats why I feel I am going wrong somewhere

Comment: In that case, if you do the operation vectorially, you're computing the pairwise distances between *all* of the points. You should instead do a for-loop, and in each iteration, apply the formula to just a single data point. Then it will be 1-by-3 times 3-by-3 time 3-by-1, to give you the 1-by-1 squared distance for that point. Repeat for all the points in Y. If you do the code above, instead you'll compute something different. I will edit my code above.